# Javascript filter table on month

Tags: javascript, filter, html-table

With help online I have managed to create a date filter on a table, where you can select a start date and it will only show the rows with that specific start date.

But I want to be able to select a month instead of a specific date and show all rows that include that month. How can I manage to do this?

My html looks something like this:

```
<div class='input-group date' id="datepick">
   Search for date: <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myInputSearches" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
</div>

<label class="noResults" align="right" style="display:none;"><b><i> No results</i></b></label>


<table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Title</th>
                    <th scope="col">From</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> Watchlist 1 </td>
                    <td> 01-02-2022</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Watchlist 2</td>
                    <td> 10-02-2022</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
   
    $('#myInput').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    });

    $('#myInput').on('dp.change', function (e) {
     var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i");
    $("#myTable tr").hide();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
        return rex.test($(this).text());
    }).show();
    $(".noResults").hide();
    if ($("#myTable tr:visible").length == 0) {
        $(".noResults").show();
    }
    });  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple non-jQuery solution:

```js
const srch=document.getElementById("srch"), 
  trs=[...document.getElementById("tbd").children], y=new Date().getFullYear();
[...Array(25)].forEach((_,i)=>srch.append(new Option(String(i%12+1).padStart(2,"0")+"-"+(+y+Math.floor(i/12)))));

srch.addEventListener("change",ev=>trs.forEach(tr=>
 tr.style.display=tr.textContent.includes(ev.target.value)?"":"none"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='input-group date' id="datepick">
  Search for date:
  <select id="srch"><option></option></select>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>

<label class="noResults" align="right" style="display:none;"><b><i> No results</i></b></label>


<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">From</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbd">
    <tr><td> Watchlist 1</td><td> 01-02-2022</td></tr>
    <tr><td> Watchlist 2</td><td> 10-02-2022</td></tr>
    <tr><td> Watchlist 3</td><td> 25-02-2022</td></tr>
    <tr><td> Watchlist 4</td><td> 11-03-2022</td></tr>
    <tr><td> Watchlist 5</td><td> 12-04-2022</td></tr>
    <tr><td> Watchlist 6</td><td> 22-05-2022</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead of a datepicker input I use a "normal" select element. The options in this select element are generated on the base of the current date, starting at January of that year and then including the next 25 months.

Whenever a different select option has been chosen, the table filtering is started. I used a very simple mechanism that looks at the total `.textContent` of each `<tr>` element of the `<tbody id="tbd">`.